# how to listen to file execution event from a java application?

Tags: java

I want to listen to execution of files in my computer from a java application. And I need the details of those files. How to listen to file execution event?

Answer (score 1):

Right from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) -

Java 7 introduced Java `WatchService` .

> A watch service that watches registered objects for changes and
>   events. For example a file manager may use a watch service to monitor
>   a directory for changes so that it can update its display of the list
>   of files when files are created or deleted. A Watchable object is
>   registered with a watch service by invoking its register method,
>   returning a WatchKey to represent the registration. When an event for
>   an object is detected the key is signalled, and if not currently
>   signalled, it is queued to the watch service so that it can be
>   retrieved by consumers that invoke the poll or take methods to
>   retrieve keys and process events. Once the events have been processed
>   the consumer invokes the key's reset method to reset the key which
>   allows the key to be signalled and re-queued with further events.

Comment: We can use WatchService to identify only the creation, deletion and modification of files. But I need to listen to file execution event.

Comment: What is file "execution event"? Please give an example.

Comment: When I play a mp3 file. I need to get the details of that file. Actually the event of the file is been read.

Comment: No that is out of scope of standard library

Comment: Oups, that's a great problem. IMHO you cannot do that in pure Java. There are kernel interfaces for Linux and Windows, search for file system audit on your prefered system. But it is off topic here ...